# Create MQTT topics on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, paho

Can someone please suggest me how can I create topics on AWS server? I knew that it will create topic automatically when I publish a message by giving the topic name but is there any way I can add all possible topics on server?

[image]

In the above image I am able to send message on a topic (test_topic) and it create that automatically on server. Is there any way I created all topics at one time on a server?

Comment: I'm confused, this has nothing to do with mosquitto at all and you've included a screen shot from HiveMQ

Comment: In screenshot I just showed that test_topic is automatically created. I want to define my topics at one time on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topics are meaningless until a message is published to it.

There is nothing to create in advance, you can subscribe to any topic you want even if no messages have ever been published to.

Also ACLs to control access to topics do not depend on a topic "existing" before they are created.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the confirmation that topics are meaningless until message publish to it.